# VBA how to update cell that ran the module with the output value

Tags: excel, vba, function, optimization, module

I am trying to return the number of cells in CellRange that have a background colour of TargetCell. Please see my code below:

```
Public Function CountByColor(CellRange As Range, TargetCell As Range)
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim TargetColor As Long, Count As Long, C As Range

TargetColor = Evaluate("cfcolour(" & TargetCell.Address & ")")
For Each C In CellRange
If Evaluate("Cfcolour(" & C.Address & ")") = TargetColor Then Count = Count + 1

Next C
CountByColor = Count

 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
Function CFColour(Cl As Range) As Double
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

 Application.EnableEvents = False
   CFColour = Cl.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

Application.EnableEvents = True
End Function
```

When I run this module it works perfectly, but when I comment my code (as it keeps running), the values in the cells disappear. So, as an alternate, I have been copy and pasting the cell results before commenting the code. Is there a way for me to replace the cell's function call with the actual output value? so that I only need to run the code once without having to comment and uncomment my code.

Thank you

mentioned in the description above.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I comment my code (as it keeps running)"? And why do you use `Evaluate` instead of comparing the color directly: `IF c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = TargetColor`?

Comment: @Ike so I uncomment my code, click on a cell that uses the function and press enter. This makes the module run. Once it has completed running, I need to comment the code or it will run every time I make a change. Is there a way I can optimise this?

I did originally use `IF c.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = TargetColor` but it results in #VALUE! so I found using Evaluate calling the CFColour function worked.

Comment: so you use this function as a UDF?

Comment: Are you using conditional formatting in your range? If not you could use `c.Interior.Color`. `DisplayFormat` doesn't work within a UDF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.displayformat?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dde-DE%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144251);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: If you are using conditional formatting - why don't you use a formula which checks for the same rules as the cf and count those results.

Comment: @Ike yes, I'm using conditional formatting, how would I use it in a formula? (that would be a better solution)

Comment: If your rule for red is e.g. value >= 10, then use e.g. `=COUNTIF(A2:A6,">=10")`

Comment: I have different conditional format rules for each column, and the cells contain data, so I won't be able to use a COUNTIF on the actual values.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
'This can be called from a worksheet as a UDF
Public Function CountByColor(CellRange As Range, TargetCell As Range) As Long
    Dim TargetColor As Long, c As Range
    
    TargetColor = CFWrapper(TargetCell)
    For Each c In CellRange
        If CFWrapper(c) = TargetColor Then CountByColor = CountByColor + 1
    Next c
End Function

'Returns the `DisplayFormat` Fill color of a cell, using Evaluate to
'  side-step limitations on what a UDF can do 
Function CFWrapper(c As Range) As Long
    'use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` method, not the default `Application.Evaluate`
    CFWrapper = c.Worksheet.Evaluate("Cfcolour(" & c.Address(0, 0) & ")")
End Function

'called from Evaluate via the worksheet
Function CFColour(c As Range) As Long
    CFColour = c.DisplayFormat.Interior.COLOR
End Function
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for you reply. Could you explain how this works?

Comment: See comments for info. Is there some specific part you’re having problems with?